# Making a replacement for a 16-bit installer, program needs short filenames?

Tags: installation, compatibility, inno-setup, mode, 16-bit

I have an old game (Westwood Monopoly CD-ROM) that only has a 16-bit installer so it won't run on my Windows 7 x64. To get around this I decided to use Inno Setup to make a new installer. The game itself is 32-bit but not LFN aware and will run on Vista/7, however the game will crash if the installer I built with Inno Setup is not run with Windows 95 compatibility checked.

There are no file or attribute differences between the folder generated by having compatibility mode on and the folder generated with no compatibility settings checked. However, the game will only run in the folder installed with compatibility mode, the game exe (Monopoly.exe) itself cannot have any compatibility mode option enabled or the game terminates whenever you try to save, load, or choose one of the computer ai player files. If compatibility mode for 95 is turned on for Monopoly.exe in the folder created without compatibility mode set for the installer, the game will load but will be unplayable for the above reasons.

My guess is that the Windows 95 setting forces short filenames to be created, while without it the game cannot find it's files because the short filename information isn't there. Having compatibility mode set for the installer is not the ideal solution since I need to be able to copy a different exe based on the version of Windows detected (Aero causes part of the screen to be cut off so I use a hex edited exe with a bigger default size).

So my question is this: Is there a way to force Inno setup to create the short filename information as it copies, or is there a way to add that with a command after it is finished (ie. repair the broken folder so the game can find its files)?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, the problem is that the newer version of Windows Installer and Windows itself no longer support the use of short names.  That property has been phased out of use and as of (AFIK) Vista it is flat out not used.  Most modern installer technologies will give you an error if you try to include them.  Have you tried looking at [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/)?  That might also allow you to run it without the need for a special installer.

Comment: The game is for Windows, DosBox will be of no use. It turns out the problem was unrelated to file names, the problem was with Microsoft's Application Compatibility Database inconsistently applying the Ignore Privileged Instruction compatibility fix. I hadn't even heard of this until I googled Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit 5.6.